# Shrink polygon to a specific area by offsetting

Tags: polygon, offset, area

I have a 2D polygon that I want to shrink by a specific offset (A) to match a certain area ratio (R) of the original polygon.
Is there a formula or algorithm for such a problem? I am interested in a simple solution for a triangle/quad but also a solution for complex polygons.

I attached an image for explanation. The original polygon is offset by A (equal-distant for each edge). A has to be chosen so that the new polygon has a specific area. In this example it should have half the area of the initial polygon.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very nonspecific, but here is one way to do what you are looking for, assuming I understand what you are asking. Note that this may cause an undesirable offset in position which you will have to deal with in some way. Not knowing what point you want to scale the polygon about, these solutions assume the simplest circumstances.

The reason for the square root in all of these formulas is that area tends to change with the square of linear scaling, just as volume does with the cube of linear scaling.

For general polygon:

```
A = sqrt(R)
for each point in polygon:
    point.x := point.x * A
    point.y := point.y * A
```

For circle:

```
A = sqrt(R)
circle.radius := circle.radius * A
```

For rectangle in terms of width and height:

```
A = sqrt(R)
rect.w := rect.w * A
rect.h := rect.h * A
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I attached an image to be more specific.

Comment: The problem you show in that picture is somewhat difficult to solve because some polygons may end up being segmented into two or more separate shapes. Let me think on it for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I realize the question is very old and you may no longer care, but I found your question when researching resources for a programming task that was in development for a contest.

The task is accessible [here](https://open.kattis.com/problems/girdingaherping).

The gist of the problem is your question, given a polygon, by how much distance should all sides be shifted inwards in order to obtain a similar polygon with an area that is half the original area.

The solution is to binary search the distance, in each iteration trying the shift and computing the new intersection points of adjacent segments, but you have to be a bit careful. To compute the intersection points you have to think of the shifted segment temporarily as lines instead, then you can compute their start and end points.

Lets assume you order the segments such that the intersection points of adjacent segments are in counter-clockwise order. There are a few cases in the binary search:

1. If you shift way too much, then you may invert the polygon, but if this happens then your counterclockwise set of points will usually become clockwise. You also need to check whether some global extrema is still a local extrema, with regard to its neighbors. For example, take the point with the minimum y-coordinate and verify in each iteration that it has a lower y-coordinate than its two neighboring points. This means you should try a lower shift in the next iteration.
2. If you shift a little less too much, the polygon may not be simple anymore or you may lose intersection points and segments. You can detect this with a sweep line algorithm. This also means you should try a lower shift in the next iteration.
3. If you shift too much then the area of the polygon will be less than half of the original, but still positive. You may want to check for negative area specifically due to floating point inaccuracies. This also means you should try a lower shift in the next iteration.
4. If you shift too little then the area of the polygon will be more than half of the original. This means you should try a higher shift in the next iteration.

If your binary search finds an area that is less than half the original area in any iteration, then it is possible to find a polygon with exactly half the area and you will obtain the correct shift after the binary search has completed.